# How to get variable from one Ajax function to work in another Ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting use a variable that I create through data being sent from php in one ajax function in a another ajax function. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried creating making this a global variable by doing `var nameOutput` and also tried `var nameOutput = 0`. You will see alert code in the second ajax function. This is outputting nothing. If I remove the `.val()`, I receive object Object.

The code in question is in the second Ajax function: `data: {
            'nameOutput': nameOutput.val()
        }`

Does anyone have any idea what I have to do?

```
var nameOutput;

$('#shuffle').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/name-selection.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            nameOutput = $('#name-output').html(data);
            $(nameOutput).html();
        },
        complete:function(){
            $('#send-info').slideDown(1500);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
//var datastring1 = $('#name-output').serialize();
$('.check').click(function() {
    alert(nameOutput.val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/name-selection-send.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'nameOutput': nameOutput.val()
        }
        ,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'Error!') {
                alert('Unable to  submit inquiry!');
                alert(data);
            } else {
                $('#success-sent').html(data);
            }
        },
        complete:function(){

        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The write statement is `nameOutput = $('#name-output').html(data)`, and you expect to read something back with `nameOutput.val()`!

Comment: Changing a DOM node's descendents (eg with `.html(...)`) will not, on its own, change any of that node's properties (eg `value`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can set inner html of nameOutput using `.html('blah')` , so you can extract the html again using `nameOutput.html()` not `nameOutput.val()`;

however I think you have to define the element like this to be a HTML element:

```
var nameOutput=$('<div></div>');
```

also in first ajax function,set the html using this:

```
nameOutput.html(data);
```

and if there is a real element with ID `name-output` , and you want the result to be visible, do both of these:

```
nameOutput.html(data);
$('#name-output').html(data);
```

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to render the html in just plain text? (without the code look)?

Comment: Yes. Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`